power automate update row when condition is met
I am new to power automate and getting response from Forms into excel sheet. i have total of 16 rows which once recorded, the flow should check if row number 16 is there it should go to row number 1 and update record and then update second row when another response is submitted and so on. as soon it reaches to row number 16 again the same process applied. Please help to achieve this.

Could you share screen shot of your Form and Excel to get some idea. Will Excel be empty initially?

yes it is just couple of questions which is submitted on form and getting updated in excel sheet. i simply want when the record reaches in excel to row number 16 the flow gets row number 1 and overwrite the data and so on.

You can keep your Form attached to the existing excel sheet and create another sheet or workbook where you can add your data till row 16 or row 1 as per your business logic using Power Automate flow. Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sH2oyAA8g-Q ....You will get some reference on internet for the same.
